# How to copy file into /data?

Tags: android

I use T2Q210 versions and android 4 systems.

I try to copy executable file lcd into sd card, then copy in /data. But there is not copy command in android. I try mv. But it hints device link error.

I try cat  lcd > /data/. There is lcd in data, but file lcd Execute failure.

My problem is:

1. How to copy file in /data?
2. Is my lcd file des break down when cat?
3. Is android could execute the linux executable file which I cross compile?

Comment: If the phone isn't rooted, you can't write it there.  If it is rooted, try using "adb push" from a PC

Comment: Root your tablet and install Busybox or just install Total Commander

Answer (score 0):

You don't have write access of  /data folder unless your device is rooted.
However I found I have write access of **/data/local/tmp** on my Samsung S4 running android 4.3.

So please try :

```
adb -d push your_exe /data/local/tmp

adb -d shell

/data/local/tmp/your_exe
```